# How to manage browser favorites with Chrome?

Tags: nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android

How can I manage the position of my favorite links in the grid of chrome?

I have several favorite in the default grid, but the position is determined by the order of saving. I would like to order my favourites by needed (by use for e.g.).

I use chrome with no extensions on Nexus 4 with Kitkat 4.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test this approach because my Chrome for Android didn't sync with Chromium on PC. However, the approach theoretically should work.

1. Make sure Chrome browser both on Android and on PC is synced to same same account. See [Why sign in to Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?hl=en).
2. When the bookmarks get synced, launch Chrome on PC and type `chrome://bookmarks` in the URL bar. It will open **Bookmarks Manager**.
3. In the left pane, choose **Mobile Bookmarks**.
4. Hold a bookmark entry and drag it to your desired position.
5. Wait for the sync to take place and see whether the changes are reflected in the Chrome for Android.

If yes, do tell me!

---

**This approach requires a rooted device.** Bookmarks are saved in the file `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Bookmarks` and the backup in `Bookmarks.bak`.

Simply pull that file into PC or edit it in Android. Before attempting to edit make sure that Chrome is not running. Force-stop it using **Settings  → Applications → All apps → Chrome → Force Stop**.

1. This is a typical look of a Bookmarks file having two bookmarks.

```
"children": [ {
   "date_added": "13086476457495966",
   "id": "9",
   "name": "Stack Overflow",
   "type": "url",
   "url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"            
}, {
   "date_added": "13086471687779090",
   "id": "6",
   "name": "Index of /sdcard/Movies/",
   "type": "url",
   "url": "file:///sdcard/Movies/"
} ],
"date_added": "13086470816073516",
"date_modified": "13086477795302443",
"id": "3",
"name": "Mobile bookmarks",
"type": "folder"
```

2. In order to change the position of a bookmark with the other, interchange the following lines of the bookmarks:

```
"date_added": "13086471687779090",
"id": "6",
"name": "Index of /sdcard/Movies/",
"type": "url",
"url": "file:///sdcard/Movies/"
```

3. Save the file and remove the `Bookmarks.bak`.
4. Launch Chrome, go to Bookmarks and the changes would be reflected.